# Bash script with a split terminal window: one side for progress/prompts, other side for verbose output

Tags: bash, logging, terminal, screen, stdout

Is it possible to have a bash script split the terminal window horizontally at one point, so that the left side details the overall progress of tasks, and the right side contains verbose output from the current task being run?

[image: screenshot]

I've found some people referencing `nohup` and `screen` in contexts of splitting the terminal window, but I don't know how to get that going in a bash script sense, or if its even the right direction for my needs.

At the moment, I've got lots of long tasks with long output, so I'm sending the output of each to a cumulative log file, instead of dumping on the screen. Then, as an interim, manually opening a new terminal window to use `watch tail LogFile*` to keep an eye on what's going on.

It would be great if I could automate that process.

### Update

Some leads.

[This post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261531/how-to-send-output-from-one-terminal-to-another-without-making-any-new-pipe-or-f) and its comments were very helpful, to establish that you can launch a command in one window and send its output to another based on its **pts** value.

For example, `ls > /dev/pts/7` will display output of `ls` in the terminal window at pts/7.

Still stumped about how to automate splitting the screen programatically, and using that, instead of a new window.

Comment: One tool you can use to have multiple tabs (also side by side) in a single window is tmux, but I don't know if it has a scripting interface.

Comment: It does, I've written scripts for tmux before. This is likely OP's best bet

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Care to share any resources that you found valuable to working with tmux? It's completely new to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a working example going with [Terminator](https://gnometerminator.blogspot.com/).

Start the bash script below in a new Terminator window:

`terminator --command="bash /path/to/script"`

And once we're running in that, it's a bit of a hack solution, but to split the screen by command-line in the bash script, I ended up using `xdotool` to send keybindings to Terminator. Like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

    # send keybinding that splits screen vertically
    xdotool key Ctrl+Shift+E
    # Terminator now sets focus to the right side (the new split) by default, so send keybinding that returns the focus to our left side
    # sleep a tiny little bit first
    sleep 0.01
    xdotool key Alt+Left

    # now to send output to the right side, let's work out "where" the ride side is
        # use who to find the pts ids of all currently spanwed terminal windows
        # use tail to find the last line from who (which we assume is the terminal window we just split)
        # then grep to find just the number after pts/
        ## windowID=$(who | tail -n1 | grep -oP 'pts/\K[0-9]*')
        # updated this to fix bug where who does not return pts values
        # https://askubuntu.com/questions/1110203
        windowID=$(ps -u $USER -o tty | awk 'NR>1 && $1 != "?" {a[$0]++};END{for(val in a) print val}' | tail -n1 | grep -oP 'pts/\K[0-9]*')

    # now we can send output from commands to the right side split window by using its pseudo device id. for example:
    ls -lah >> /dev/pts/$windowID

exit
```